# trouble declaring a variable as a specific cell on a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Very new to VBA. i am having trouble declaring a variable as a specific cell on a worksheet.

I have tried defining the cell by rows and columns but when I put a watch on the line it says Value is out of context.  The variable is testname and it is in cell E2 of the worksheet I have set as the variable raw.

```
Sub findcomponents()

    Dim raw As Worksheet
    Dim res As Worksheet
    Dim temp As Worksheet
    Dim testname As String
    Dim finalrow1 As Integer
    Dim finalrow2 As Integer
    Dim i As Integer



    Set raw = Worksheets("rawdata")
    Set res = Worksheets("resultcomponents")
    Set temp = Worksheets("uploadtemplate")

    testname = raw.Range("E2").Value


    finalrow1 = raw.Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row
    finalrow2 = res.Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To finalrow2
        If res.Cells(i, 4) = testname Then
            Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 4)).Copy
            temp.Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Cells("A2").Paste
        End If
    Next i

    End Sub
```

I expect the value to be the string in the E2 cell
Edit:  I added the rest of the code.  When I run it doesn't do anything.
It is supposed to take the string testname and loop through a list on the res worksheet and return the matches.  I put a watch on the testname line because i thought it would show me that it was comparing the correct string and the Value in the watch line says

yes the paste line is incorrect. I also tried temp.Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Paste  and this makes it angry also.

The fix works with an edit on the worksheet name.  But there is more than 1 match on the res worksheet. That is why I thought finding the the last row (but I should have offset 1 row) would return all the matches.  This does work to return all values.
   temp.Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Is there a better way to do this not using Range("A10000").End(xlUp)?

Comment: "Value is out of context" doesn't sound like a VBA error message.  What's the exact error you get, and on which line?

Comment: This looks like an error in the testing procedure. Add this line at the bottom of your code and run it again. `MsgBox "E2 = " & testname`

Comment: What value is in `cell E2`

Comment: BCR/ABL P190 is the string in E2

Comment: The error you're getting is only for the watch. The variable you're trying to watch is not in scope at the point you're looking at the watch.

Comment: what @KenWhite said. The error isnt the `testname` Step thru pressing `F8` which line is the error on?

Comment: This errors on the paste line (unless OP didn't paste in his line break `_`)

Comment: maybe the watch didn't mean anything.  when I run the sub now it says Run-time error '5'"   Invalid procedure call or argument.  On the  temp.Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Cells("A2").Paste - when I debug

Comment: urdearboy is right.  the error is on the paste line.

Comment: Stop adding information in comments. Instead, [edit] your post and put the details there, where they can be seen. They're of no use buried in comments.

Comment: I see that as I have it - it would not paste into the next line down each time. But nothing is happening.    I'm sorry I don't know where the below solutions are that were referred to.

Comment: @idodna scroll down....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Your key problem is with the paste statement.

You can use one of the two following methods to paste (although it should be noted that there are others)

```
Range.Copy PasteRange
```

or

```
Range.Copy
PasteRange.PasteSpecial (paste type (values, formats, etc.))
```

---

This has also been updated with more standard variable blocks/variable names for `Last Row` calculations. Also, notice that I have also updated the `Last Row` calculation to be a little more dynamic. Lastly, swapping `Integer` for `Long`

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub findcomponents()

Dim raw As Worksheet: Set raw = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("rawdata")
Dim res As Worksheet: Set res = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resultcomponents")
Dim temp As Worksheet: Set temp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("uploadtemplate")

Dim testname As String
Dim LR1 As Long, LR2 As Long, LR3 As Long, i As Long

LR1 = raw.Range("A" & raw.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  '<-- This variable is never used??
LR2 = res.Range("A" & res.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  '<-- Updated for standard Last Row (LR) calculation

For i = 2 To LR2
    If res.Cells(i, 4) = raw.Range("E2") Then
        res.Range(res.Cells(i, 2), res.Cells(i, 4)).Copy  '<-- Qaulified Ranges!!
        LR3 = temp.Range("A" & temp.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
        temp.Range("A" & LR3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues '<-- Correct Paste Method
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

*The naming conventions used are just my preference. To an extent, you are free to name variables however you see fit*

Comment: I'm sorry - I will learn the etiquette as I go.  urdearboy - this works with a small change - it should be raw.Range("E2") Then

Comment: if I have a follow up question do I edit - or put it here?

Comment: @idodna this site works when specific questions get specific answers. Any new question should include your updated code and present a new issue - you cannot continuously update one post with a forever changing question. If that were allowed, no question would ever really be answered - only temporarily answered.

Comment: You should also take the time to see if you can figure out the issue solo! It's a great learning exercise - if you cannot figure out the issue, post a new question :)

Comment: I did fix it.  But since you thought I was using outdated tools.  I wanted to see if you thought there was a better one.

Comment: Who said anything about outdated tools?

Comment: I don't have any VBA vocabulary - I was just trying to find the right words - its all good